# Is there a diagram of conditional events that are independent, that are no longer independent unconditionally?

Tags: probability

I understand that conditional independence doesn't necessarily imply unconditional independence.

I also understand that having unconditional independence doesn't necessarily imply that events will be independent after we have a condition. I have worked through a couple examples which demonstrate this, and the diagram of having unconditional independence not implying independence once we condition for something is attached.

This got me thinking, is there a diagram of the other one?

[Image of two events that are unconditionally independent, but once we condition upon them, they are disjoint and so not independent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfUE9.png)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "of the other one"? What about the condition that never happens? Two events that never happen are independent.

Comment: Sorry - I should have been more precise posting on a Math forum! I would like to see a Venn Diagram (like the one posted) where the events are non-negative and the conditioning is non-negative as well.

Comment: In general the independence property relies on the underlying probability measure, and thus Venn's diagram is not a suitable/sufficient tool to study these properties. For the same pair of events inside the same sample space and event space, if you assign two different probability function $P$ and $Q$, they can be independent under one of them but dependent under other. The linked diagram is showing conditionally mutually exclusive, and thus conditionally dependent.

Comment: Now imagine there are two big sets $A, B$ with little intersection, so it "seems" that they are not independent - $P(A), P(B)$ is big while $P(A \cap B)$ is too small. Now draw another set $C$, suitably covering the intersection, such that $P(A|C) = P(B|C) = 1/2, P(A \cap B|C) = 1/4$ then they will be independent.